# labeling, numbering loop elements + summing them up

Tags: python-2.7

```
import math
from decimal import Decimal

def s(x):
    return (Decimal(0.298**k))/Decimal(math.factorial(k))

prevSK = 0
sum=0

for k in (range(0,501)):
    try:
        a = (round(s(k),5))
        r = (round(s(k)/prevSK,5))
        print a
        print r
        prevSK = s(k)
        summa = sum=sum+a
    except Exception, e:
        print e
        prevSK = (Decimal(s(k),))

    continue

print "The sum is:", summa
```

This is what I get when I run this program with 5 elements in loop

```
 x / 0
 0.298
 0.298
 0.0444
 0.149
 0.00441
 0.09933
 0.00033
 0.0745
 The sum is: 0.34714
```

This how far I got. I need label these elements (a1, r1, a2, r2...) and I cant figure out how.

I need those a elements to be like from 1 to 500 and if its possible on the second column r elements from 1 to 500.

And after all that I have to sum up a elements, like Summa = sum of all a elements. (UPDATE: already found how to do that, as you can see in the code above)

If someone could help me with this I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure exactly if you want to print them with a label or add them to a list..

But you could go this way:

```
import math
from decimal import Decimal

def s(x):
    return (Decimal(0.298**k))/ Decimal(math.factorial(k))

prevSK = 0
sum=0
valueList = {}
for k in (range(0,501)):

    try:
        a = (round(s(k),5))
        r = (round(s(k)/prevSK,5))
        print "a{n}: {a}".format(n=k, a=a)
        print "r{n}: {r}".format(n=k, r=r)
        valueList[k] = {"a{n}".format(n=k) : a, "r{n}".format(n=k) : r}
        prevSK = s(k)
        summa = sum=sum+a
    except Exception, e:
        print e
        prevSK = (Decimal(s(k),))

    continue

print "The sum is:", summa
```